# Chrome Loading an Old Version of Javascript File

Tags: php, javascript, apache, google-chrome

I am building a web application using CodeIgniter.

The problem that I'm having is that chrome is loading an older version of my javascript file main.js

My Code:

```
$(document).load(function(){

/******************************************
*                                         *
*              AJAX FUNCTIONS             *
*                                         *
******************************************/    

function deactivate_dept_member(user_id, token_name, token_hash, callback)
{
    $.post(
        site_url('/ajax/deactivate_dept_member'),
        {
            'user_id':usr_id,
            token_name:token_hash
        },

        function(result){
            var response = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
            callback(response);
        }
    );
}

function activate_dept_member(usr_id, token_name, token_hash, callback)
{
    $.post(
        site_url('/ajax/activate_dept_member'),
        {
            'user_id':usr_id,
            token_name:token_hash
        },

        function(result){
            var response = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
            callback(response);
        }
    );
}

function get_dept_users_for_session(dept_id, token_name, token_hash, callback)
{
    $.post(
        site_url('ajax/get_dept_users_for_session'),
        {
            "dept_id":dept_id,
            token_name:token_hash

        },

        function(result){
            var response = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
            callback(response);
        }
    );

}

function invite_dept_user(email_address, first_name, last_name, admin, token_name, token_hash, callback)
{
    $.post(
        site_url('ajax/invite_dept_user'),
        {
            "email_address":email_address,
            "first_name":first_name,
            "last_name":last_name,
            "admin":admin,
            token_name:token_hash
        },
        function(result){
            var response = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
            callback(response);
        }
    );
}

function get_department_members(dept_id, token_name, token_hash, callback)
{
    $.post(
        site_url('ajax/det_department_members'),
        {
            "dept_id":dept_id,
            token_name:token_hash
        },
        function(result){
            var response = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
            callback(response);
        }
    );
}




/******************************************
*                                         *
*              UTILITY FUNCTIONS          *
*                                         *
******************************************/
function site_url(add_on)
{
    return 'http://localhost:8080/app/index.php'+add_on;
}

function getUserTypeString(user_status)
{
    switch(user_status)
    {
        case "1":
            return "Invited";
        case "2":
            return "Active";
        case "3":
            return "Inactive";
        default:
            return "";
    }
}


function isDepartmentAdmin(user_role)
{
    if(user_role == 2){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function get_error_message(error_code)
{
    switch(error_code)
    {
        case "20130":
            return 'The username already exists';
        default:
            return 'A general error occured';
    }
}


})
```

What Chrome Says Is My Source:

```
/******************************************
*                                         *
*              AJAX FUNCTIONS             *
*                                         *
******************************************/    

function deactivate_dept_member(user_id, token_name, token_hash, callback)
{
    $.post(
        site_url('/ajax/deactivate_dept_member'),
        {
            'user_id':usr_id,
            token_name:token_hash
        },

        function(result){
            var response = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
            callback(response);
        }
    );
}

function activate_dept_member(usr_id, token_name, token_hash, callback)
{
    $.post(
        site_url('/ajax/activate_dept_member'),
        {
            'user_id':usr_id,
            token_name:token_hash
        },

        function(result){
            var response = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
            callback(response);
        }
    );
}

function get_dept_users_for_session(dept_id, token_name, token_hash, callback)
{
    $.post(
        site_url('ajax/get_dept_users_for_session'),
        {
            "dept_id":dept_id,
            token_name:token_hash

        },

        function(result){
            var response = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
            callback(response);
        }
    );

}

public function invite_dept_user(email_address, first_name, last_name, admin, token_name, token_hash, callback)
{
    $.post(
        site_url('ajax/invite_dept_user'),
        {
            "email_address":email_address,
            "first_name":first_name,
            "last_name":last_name,
            "admin":admin,
            token_name:token_hash
        },
        function(result){
            var response = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
            callback(response);
        }
    );
}

public function get_department_members(dept_id, token_name, token_hash, callback)
{
    $.post(
        site_url('ajax/det_department_members'),
        {
            "dept_id":dept_id,
            token_name:token_hash
        },
        function(result){
            var response = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
            callback(response);
        }
    );
}




/******************************************
*                                         *
*              UTILITY FUNCTIONS          *
*                                         *
******************************************/
function site_url(add_on)
{
    return 'http://localhost:8080/app/index.php'+add_on;
}

function getUserTypeString(user_status)
{
    switch(user_status)
    {
        case "1":
            return "Invited";
        case "2":
            return "Active";
        case "3":
            return "Inactive";
        default:
            return "";
    }
}

function isDepartmentAdmin(user_role)
{
    if(user_role == 2){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function get_error_message(error_code)
{
    switch(error_code)
    {
        case "20130":
            return 'The username already exists';
        default:
            return 'A general error occured';
    }
}


 �����������������
```

Things I've Done To Try and Fix the Problem

- Disabled Cache using Chrome Developer Tools
- Using the LiveReload Extension/App
- Restarted Apache
- Verified that the sharing for Vagrant is working correctly (The file is the same in the virtual centos instance I have running as it is on my Mac)
- Tried to get chrome to load a different version of the file (adding a ?2 to the end of the url to the file: localhost:8080/app/assets/js/main.js?2)

Other Things to Note:

- This also happens in Firefox and Safari so the problem may lie with Apache but I can't test this theory because I can't get the oci8 extension for php to compile for any other OS.

Edit:

More things I've tried

- renaming file ( will work for a little bit but the problem starts happening again.)

Comment: Have you tried viewing the site in Incognito mode?

Comment: Random though, the name of your file (down the case) is the same?, remember in Windows Main and main are the same but not in Linux. Also have you tried to clean the cache, not just disabling it?

Comment: The same thing happens in incognito mode and the case is the same. I cleaned the cache before disabling it.

Comment: Maybe try renaming the file & update the link in your code (perhaps to `main_.js`). A bit of a hacky fix, but it'd eliminate some issues at least.

Comment: I've tried that, the file used to be named app.js, updated post to mention this.

Comment: Did you manually clear the cache contents from Chrome?

Comment: yes, as I said above I cleaned the cache before disabling it.

Comment: Have you tried doing a "hard refresh" with Shift+F5? If clearing the cache didn't work, this probably won't either, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: I got it to work for a minute but then I made another change and now there are a couple of lines at the bottom of the main.js file that aren't showing in the source.

Answer (score 2):

If it works upon rename, and then *stops working*, then *it can not be* a cache of any kind (except maybe "a seriously broken one") nor a file modifying thing (e.g. BOM, rogue CR's, etc.).

But I'm guessing that the file works, and then *it stops working* not "after a while" but "after you save it again making what seems to be a very minor and unrelated change".

If this is the case you're probably dealing with rogue CR's or weird EOF handling: try checking the file on disk with a different editor (a hex editor ideally), and/or opening it with the *simplest* text editor you have.

If you have a bare CR as the last character of the file, some editors and platforms will add two "strange characters" (actually another LF and another rogue CR) every time you read/write the file again. And those same editors *won't* show you those characters, so you won't be able to delete them from those editors.

**UPDATE**:
Another distinct possibility is that you have a "hidden" UTF-8 character (or fragment thereof) which is not correctly detected. Then something very like this happens:

[Visual Studio 2008 project file does not load because of an unexpected encoding change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498959/visual-studio-2008-project-file-does-not-load-because-of-an-unexpected-encoding)

...and notice that the strange characters you are getting are *exactly* the UTF8 signification for *encoding error*, which also would explain why Chrome detects an *unexpected end of input*.

Try blindly selecting from the last few lines of code to the end of the file and *delete* the selection, then write it back:

```
            return 'A general error occurred';
        }
    }
})
/* END OF FILE */
```

and save. This *ought* to clear things. Check with the hex editor from 'occurred' onwards if any strange characters are present.

Comment: i think this is getting close to the core of what's happening. I looked at the file in a hex editor but doesn't seem to be any rogue carriage returns or end of file marks. But right now when trying to load that file I'm getting an "Unexpected end of input" error in chrome

Comment: I'm now convinced your editor has been unfaithful to you, and I believe I also know how. Edited answer.

Comment: Hmm, this is happening in all my text editors on my mac, sublime text, vim even textedit. Textedit seems to be the only one not breaking it but it adds an invalid character at the end of the file.

Comment: Weirder and weirder. Do you have the Terminal utility 'hex' available (I'm not familiar with MacOS)? If so, try issuing the command `hex yourjavascriptfile.js | grep -A2 -B2 " [89a-f][0-9a-f] "` and see whether it spits out any non-ASCII characters. It will also show two lines after and before the culprit, so you can better locate it.

Comment: I deleted the file and rewrote it completely but the problem still occurs. I do see a bunch of � characters at the end of the file when looking at the main.js soure in chrome now but I don't see these characters when looking at the the file in a hex editor or in notepad++. Also the majority of the middle of the file is missing.

Comment: Worked for me - removed extra lines at end of file and added a newline in Visual Studio 2008